# How do I consistently flatten a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```
from numpy import array, eye, matrix

x = array([1, 0])
A = eye(2)
print(A.dot(x))
```

prints `[1. 0.]`.

On the other hand,

```
B = matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
print(B.dot(x))
```

prints `[[1 0]]` which is a 1-by-2 array. Furthermore,

```
print(B.dot(x).flatten())
```

also prints `[[1 0]]`.

This is rather annoying. Why does flatten fail here and how else can I get this into the 1-d shape?

Comment: Why are you using `matrix`? You have this problem because you're using `matrix`.

Comment: Because this is the minimal example that causes the problem. In actual practice I'm constructing something more sophisticated than the identity matrix.

Comment: Are you saying your real code *doesn't* use `matrix`?

Comment: It does, just not to construct the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `matrix`. [`numpy.matrix.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.flatten.html#numpy.matrix.flatten) returns a 1-row matrix, because that's as flat as `matrix` instances get. If for some reason you are dead set on using `matrix`, convert to ndarray with [`matrix.A`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A.html#numpy.matrix.A) before flattening:

```
flat = whatever_matrix.A.flatten()
```

or just use `A1` to get a flat ndarray directly:

```
flat = whatever_matrix.A1
```